# Remove text formatting tags

Tags: php, html

I want to remove all formatting tags of from a string (to show a kinda of summary). To achieve this, I used the `str_replace` method from PHP. here is my code :

```
<?php $tags_to_delete = array('<p>', '<h?>', '<b>', '<i>', '<u>', '<strike>', '<code>','<blockquote>','<font color="#??????">','<font color="#???">', '<font size="?">', '<center>', '<em>', '<font face="?">', '<strong>', '</p>', '</h?>', '</b>', '</i>', '</u>', '</strike>', '</code>','</blockquote>','</font>', '</center>', '</em>', '</strong>');?>

$article->description = str_replace($tags_to_delete, "", $article->description);
$article->description=substr($article->description,0,150).'...'; 
echo $article->description; 
die();
```

It works great for all tags except the `<font color="#??????">` and `<font face="?">` . In other programming language, I've always used the `?` symbol to select **any** value, it could be 'a' or '2', the `?` character should represent anything. Is this different in PHP ? If someone can help me with this, I'd be really thankful !

Comment: Use `strip_tags` and just specify the tags you want to keep: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Man... i'm feeling too dumb. Really thanks. can you add an answer so i can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and just specify the tags you want to keep, for example:

```
$article->description = strip_tags($article->description, '<a><img>');
```